# How do I use URL-Rewrite with Windows Authentication

Tags: iis, iis-10

I have inherited a series of web apps, which all sit below the single default site of the iis server.  These are accessed using an internal DNS server, then URLrewrite to access each application.

One of the applications uses windows authentication, and whilst this is fine to access the landing page of the application, it then fails to pass the authentication to subsequent pages.

I have looked around and found references to ARR, but I don't really understand how this works, and I want to do as little rearchitecture as possible.

Is there a simple way to pass the authentication from the landing page to subsequent pages?

I've looked around on google and only really seen references to ARR, which I'm not really sure about

Comment: Use tools like Fiddler you should be able to track down why “it then fails to pass the authentication to subsequent pages”. Before the root cause is clear, your any further attempts are pointless.

Comment: Fiddler just returns a 401 authentication error.  It's sonething to do with the point in the HTTP process which the authentication occurs, therefore the details are not being passed with the rewrite.

Comment: Fiddler can reveal much more information, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/11/22/troubleshooting-authentication-with-fiddler/ If you find it difficult to move on, I suggest you open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and work with Microsoft support.

Comment: The whole idea of asking the question here, is that i suspect another user will have had the same issues and I was looking to gain an insight from someone with experience of the issue and the various work arounds.

"Open a support case with Microsoft" is not a particularly helpful response.